# Sanity check: Will this SQL query join how I want?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My deepest apologies for the query, that's legacy code for you. I basically want to check my code makes logical sense.

Essentially I want to return all rows of the "signatures" table where the "claim_id" = the "claim_id" on the "claims" table.

From that, I intend to check if the "signature_id" = null for each claim. If it does, that claim has no related signature, correct?

```
$SQL="
SELECT
    `claims`.`claim_id`,
    CONCAT(`insurers`.`insurer_name`,IF((`insurers`.`insurer_branch`<>''),CONCAT(' - ',`insurers`.`insurer_branch`),'')) as 'insurer',
    `claims`.`claim_number` as 'claim_number',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(claims.overflow_date) as 'overflow_date',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(claims.reassigned_date) as 'reassigned_date',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(claims.reassigned_from_fr_date) as 'reassigned_from_fr_date',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(claims.date_of_first_contact) as 'date_of_first_contact',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`claims`.`date_surveyor_made_contact`) as 'date_surveyor_made_contact',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`claims`.`date_of_inspection`) as 'date_of_inspection',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`claims`.`surveyor_completed`) as 'surveyor_completed',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CASE 1 WHEN (claims.overflow_date>0) THEN claims.overflow_date WHEN (claims.reassigned_date>0) THEN claims.reassigned_date WHEN (claims.reassigned_from_fr_date>0) THEN claims.reassigned_from_fr_date ELSE claims.date_of_first_contact END ) as 'date_of_first_contact_debug',
    `claims`.`date_surveyor_made_contact` as 'date_surveyor_made_contact_debug',
    `claims`.`date_of_inspection` as 'date_of_inspection_debug',
    `claims`.`surveyor_completed` as 'surveyor_completed_debug',
    `claims`.`letter_of_findings`,
    `claims`.`int_settlement_reason`,
    `claims`.`ext_settlement_reason`,
    `claims`.`original_surveyor_id`,
    `claims`.`surveyor_id`,
    `claims`.`broker_name`,
    `insurers`.`insurer_type`,
    `insurers`.`insurer_id`,
    `signatures`.`signature_id`,
    `signatures`.`claim_id`
FROM
    (((`claims` claims INNER JOIN `insurers` insurers ON claims.`insurer_id` = insurers.`insurer_id`)
    INNER JOIN `users` users ON claims.surveyor_id = users.user_id) 
    LEFT JOIN `signatures` signatures on claims.claim_id = signatures.claim_id)
WHERE
    (`claims`.`claim_type` <> ".$conn->qstr(TYPE_DESKTOP).") AND 
    (`claims`.`claim_type` <> ".$conn->qstr(TYPE_AUDIT).") AND  
    (`claims`.`insurer_id` NOT IN ('".implode("','",$arrSURGE)."')) AND 
    (`users`.`status` = ".$conn->qstr(STATUS_LIVE).") AND
    (`claims`.`claim_cancelled_id` = 0) AND
    $where
";
```

The code I've added is both the `signatures`. selectors, and the `LEFT JOIN 'signatures' signatures on claims.claim_id = signatures.claim_id)` line.

claim_id is PK on the claims table, and signature_id is PK on signatures table.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It could be seen that way. I was more looking for help about how LEFT JOIN functions, and whether it will return the desired result, not to improve code that I know works.

Comment: is there a reason you cant test this yourself to check if the result is according to what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The null check will only shows items with signatures. If you leave the null check out of the picture, you will get nulls for items where signature is not present.

check this [image]

Comment: THAT's the kind of thing I was looking for. Extremely helpful, thank you.

Comment: Nice image. Where did this come from? Cite your source please. :-)